# How to make import in class gobal in python?

Tags: python, class, import

Not sure if my python question is titled correctly, but I get a `NameError: global name 'someOtherClass' is not defined` error when I try to call a method that uses a module imported through the `__init__` function of my class.

```
class myClass
    def __init__(self):
        if is_64b:
            exit()
        else:
            import someOtherClass

    def myMethod(self, param1, param2, param3):
        return someOtherClass.someMethod(param1, param2, param3)

from myFolder.myClassFileName import myClass
myObj = myClass()
value = myObj.myMethod(p1, p2, p3)
```

Comment: You are importing the name `someOtherClass` into the `__init__` method.

Comment: @StephenRauch I do not really understand what this implies. Are you saying that it is not possible to do? If I don't import into `__init__`, where can I import it such that all other methods of the class can see the import?

Comment: You will need to understand namespaces for this to make sense,  Which is why I closed as duplicate for namespaces.  Go read the answers (especially the top answer) at the duplicate question.

Comment: imports are generally done at the very top of the file unless you have special needs.